# php form did not work

Tags: php

I am trying to send  two arguments (textbox&value in checkbox) using form with specific row id

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
       echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['datef'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    $idw=$row['id'];
      }
      echo "</table>";

        echo " </br>";



      echo "<form action=\"checked.php\" method=\"POST\"  enctype=\"multipart/form- data\" >";

       echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"ids\" value=\"$idw\" ><br>";

        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"check\" value=\"0\" ><br>";

       echo "<p><input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\"  /></p>";
          echo "</form>";
```

checked.php :

```
   $idw=$_GET['ids'];
  $check=$_GET['check'];


  echo $idw;

   echo $check;

    if ($check==1){
   $sql="UPDATE image_try SET  checked=1 WHERE id=$idw";


   $q=mysql_query($sql);}
```

the problem that checked.php did not receive the arguments from the form

Comment: I really hope that SQL isn't intended to ever go on anything resembling a production server, and just temporary for a test... because with code like that, you're just begging for a drive-by SQL injection. PDO with prepared statements should be the first place you go for working with SQL in PHP, since it handles the entire issue quite nicely (`mysql_real_escape_string` has a few corner cases where you can still be bitten, and the entire idea of it is a bit obscene).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action is set to post and your checked.php is looking for GET values. Either change your form action to GET or change your variables in checked.php to $_POST

Answer (score 1):

Your form method is `POST` so you have to Use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` in php

Comment: yaah,thank you so much ,It works , I did not attention to the action ><